# HTML mail prehead not hidden

Tags: outlook, html-email

I've added a prehead text to my HTML mail, but it isn't hidden in Outlook. I added the prehead styling as inline style, and also included it in the head style tag.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <style>
        .preheader {
            color: #f6f6f6;
            display: none !important;
            max-height: 0;
            max-width: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            mso-hide: all;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size: 0;
            line-height: 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #f6f6f6; font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; padding: 10px; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
    <div class="preheader" style="color: #f6f6f6; display: none !important; max-height: 0; max-width: 0; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; mso-hide: all; overflow: hidden; font-size: 0; line-height: 1px;">
        {% block preheader %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    ...
```

Why isn't the preheader hidden? It keeps rendering as if none of the styles are applied.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that's because you have `display:none !important`, and outlook does not respect the important flag. So, change to `display:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the content in the preheader was too long. Limiting the amount of characters fixed my issue.